# aws cli to loop through rds instances

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

if I run

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[*].[DBInstanceIdentifier,AutoMinorVersionUpgrade]' --output text
```

It gives 1000's of IDs and true or false for AutoMinorVersionUpgrade:

```
db-test-admin-1-dev            True
db-test-admin-product1-dev     True
db-test-admin-legacy-dev       True
db-byodb-test                  False
db-byod-nightly                True
db-debug-oc-issue-dev          True
db-test1-dev                   True
db-test-instance-dev           True
db-exa-dev                     False
```

I want to set AutoMinorVersionUpgrade to false to all, so I do:

```
for rds in $(aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[*].DBInstanceIdentifier' --output text); 
do aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier $rds --no-auto-minor-version-upgrade ;
done
```

How can I skip running modify-db-instance if the rds instance already has AutoMinorVersionUpgrade=False?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--query` to conditionally return some items. The `--query` option support jmespath expressions.

```
for rds in $(aws rds describe-db-instances --query 'DBInstances[?AutoMinorVersionUpgrade==`true`].DBInstanceIdentifier' --output text); do
    aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier $rds --no-auto-minor-version-upgrade 
done
```